# On Linear Layout, android:animateLayoutChanges="true" so same layout animating changes while other layouts relative to this are not animating

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation, android-linearlayout

I have a Relative Layout and one Linear layout inside it and some other layout I am using

> android:animateLayoutChanges="true"

and I am dynamically deleting and adding views inside it. so linear layout itself animating up and down but other views which are relative to the linear layout are not animating.
here attaching some code here which will give more understanding.

```
<RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
        <LinearLayout id="@+id/linear_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                    android:background="#1AFFFFFF"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingTop="12dp">

        </LinearLayout>
       <RelativeLayout id="@+id/bottom_layout"
               android:below="id/linear_layout">
       </RelativeLayout>
```

so, I am adding items in linear_layout then bottom_layout suddenly changes its position, doesn't slide down and same when I remove View.
When I remove View, bottom_layout overlaps to linear_layout and then linear_layout slides up.
..
if Somebody has any solution for this please write. Thank You.